# Cannot save emojis in utf8mb3 tables… Overnight, since MariaDB 10.6 update and switching to nd_mysqli

Tags: php, mariadb, mysqlnd, mariadb-10.5, mariadb-10.6

Before, using **MariaDB 10.5** and **mysqli**, I had plenty of **old** WordPress website on **utf8mb3** tables where I can successfully save a wide range of Emojis in the database.

Now since I switched to **MariaDB 10.6** and **nd_mysqli**, if the database and tables are **not** converted to **utf8mb4**, WordPress cannot save anymore the old post that already contain emojis…

It's time consuming to troubleshoot it for WordPress users as this happen **without** any notice in the Apache **error_log** or WordPress **debug.log**. No explicit error is showed by WordPress in Classic Editor: the edit post form is just refreshing and the content is lost.
Or in the Block Editor, the error is *"Updating failed. Error message : Could not update post in the database"* and/or an Error 500 can be showed in the browser Console, with no logs in the server.

The most frustrating for the users is that, old WordPress websites, with old tables in utf8mb3, **before** successfully stored emojis in old content… and then, overnight (after the server update), the same old WordPress website cannot save content with emojis anymore.

I have tried to change the MariaDB [old_mode](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/old-mode/) which is supposed to be empty, like this in the **my.cnf** :

`old_mode=""`

From MariaDB 10.6, utf8 is by default an alias for utf8mb3, but I guess this can be changed to ut8mb4 by changing the default value of the old_mode system variable by an empty value ([more info about utf8 alias in the MariaDB unicode doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unicode/)).

But it does not work… emojis still don't save in utf8mb3 tables ***as it works before***.

• I can understand that utf8mb3 do not suit for emojis.

But…

• I cannot understand why so much old WordPress websites created in the past with utf8mb3 tables have old content with plenty emojis stored inside, that are displaying properly in the frontend and backend without being replaced by a **???** sign.

Just saving is now impossible now.

What is this new behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Consider migrating your tables to UTF-8 by converting them to use `utf8mb4` charset. The old 3 byte charset is deprecated and should not be used.

[PHP (mysqlnd) does not support `utf8mb3`](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8478). You cannot use this charset yet. If you can't convert your tables then use the alias for `utf8mb3`: `utf8`.

Comment: That's the issue.  I can't convert all the tables manually, because I have several servers that host around a thousand websites each.

Yes ! I would like to alias utf8mb3 to utf8mb4, but I don't know how to proceed. Any help ? (the MariaDB doc is not so clear about it)

I have tried to change the MariaDB my.cnf :

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
old_mode=""

It's suppose to use utf8mb4 then ? But for new database I am afraid.

Comment: Just use `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')` or however WP allows you to set this configuration.

Comment: Thank you Dharman! But again, it not help for the global infrastructure as each WordPress wp-config files cannot be changed individually for all end-users (hundreds and hundreds users). Thank you anyway for your precious feedback! Appreciate.